# Return info from jQuery AJAX call and execute additional jQuery on success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery AJAX to duplicate a background image. I am stumped as to how to effectively return information back to the original page. Here is the AJAX I send on click of "'#dupBtn"...

```
//DUPLICATE BACKGROUND      
$('#dupBtn').click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            url: "../system/bgUpdate.php",
            data: {
                "user":<?= $_POST['user'] ?>,
                "bgID":bgID,
                "refID2":<?= $_POST['refID2'] ?>,
                "refTable":"<?= $_POST['refTable'] ?>",
                "bgTitle":($('#bgTitle').val()),
                "path":path,
                "bgColor":bgColor,
                "bgPoz":bgPoz,
                "bgRepeat":bgRepeat,
                "attach":attach
                }
        });
});
```

Here is the basic MySQL query on the PHP page bgUpdate.php.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO backgrounds (user,title,path,bgColor,bgPosition,bgRepeat,bgAttachment) VALUES ('".$_POST['user']."','$title','".$_POST['path']."','$bgColor','".$_POST['bgPoz']."','$rt','$attach')");

$bgIDnew = mysql_insert_id();
```

What I want to do is have the following code fired on the original page upon successful execution of the MySQL entry, dynamically catching the '$bgIDnew' from the MySQL PHP page.

```
$('#bgPickerBox').load('../dialog/bgPickerAlbums.php?album=<?=$bgIDnew?>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the `success` attribute of the `.ajax()` function:

```
$('#dupBtn').click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        url: "../system/bgUpdate.php",
        data: {
            ...
            },
        success:
            function(response)
            {
                $('#bgPickerBox').load('../dialog/bgPickerAlbums.php?album=<?=$bgIDnew?>');
            }
    });
});
```

That's only part of it though... The other half is that your PHP needs to return something that jQuery can understand as a "successful" call. My preference is to use HTTP status codes. In your case, your PHP script should return a `200` code if it was successful; otherwise, it should return something in the `400` range. (By the way, if you want jQuery to do something separate with errors, you can use the `error` property of `.ajax()`.)

However, if you need to return data from the server to the client-side script, then your PHP can print out that information like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO backgrounds (user,title,path,bgColor,bgPosition,bgRepeat,bgAttachment) VALUES ('".$_POST['user']."','$title','".$_POST['path']."','$bgColor','".$_POST['bgPoz']."','$rt','$attach')");

$bgIDnew = mysql_insert_id();
// Best practice to keep it in some sort of understandable format
// Here, we'll put it in an associative array:
$response = array('id' => $bgIDnew);
print_r(json_encode($response));
```

This PHP script sends back to the ajax() method a JSON representation of the $response variable. You've already configured that ajax() method to read the response dataType as JSON, so it already knows how to read the `response` parameter... Which means your success function can look something like this:

```
success:
    function(response)
    {
        $('#bgPickerBox').load('../dialog/bgPickerAlbums.php?album=' + response.id);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - but how do I get the PHP variable, "$bgIDnew" back to the AJAX page to use it in the success jQuery?

Comment: Your best bet is to use PHP's function `json_encode($bglDnew)` and echo out the results. Then in your `success` function, you've got access to the `response` variable, which is the output of your PHP page. Since you're already indicating that the dataType is 'json', you can just read that `response` variable as a JSON object.

Comment: Thanks again - would you be able to demonstrate that in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has a `success` property that acts as a callback that you can use. Another is `complete` which is fired if the request is successful or not.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  /* your stuff here */
  success: function(response) {
    $('#bgPickerBox').load('../dialog/bgPickerAlbums.php?album=<?=$bgIDnew?>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write up the logic in the **success callback function** of your ajax Request..

This is fired when an ajax request is successfully returned..

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#bgPickerBox').load('../dialog/bgPickerAlbums.php?album=<?=$bgIDnew?>');
  }
```

Add this to your ajax Request...